# How to draw a rook graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, grids, edge

I'm trying to draw a `$4\times 4$` rook graph. That is, the graph whose vertices form a `$4\times 4$` grid whose edges indicate the allowed movement of the rook on a chess board.

I'm struggling to draw the edges because the code

```
draw (node1)--(node2);
```

only gives overlapping straight lines. So I'd need some way of doing this with curved edges so that the drawing looks neat. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Yes, there are many ways to do this. To get help, you should post a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output. For example, you could post a MWE with the lines crossing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely sure if this is what you need, as you don't provide a sketch.

If your graph is something like the following you can curve the edges with `to` as in

```
\draw (A) to[out=10,in=30] (B);
```

that draws a curve form A to B leaving A at an angle of 10 degrees and arriving at B with an angle of 30 degrees.

A complete example could be (or not):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% nodes
\foreach\i in {1,2,3,4} \foreach\j in {1,2,3,4}
  \node[draw,circle] (\i\j) at (\i,\j) {};
% curves
\foreach\i in {1,2,3,4} \foreach\j in {1,2,3}
{
  \pgfmathtruncatemacro\jj{\j+1}
  \foreach\k in {\jj,...,4} 
  {
    \draw (\i\j) to[out=90+18*\k-18*\jj,in=270-18*\k+18*\jj] (\i\k);
    \draw (\j\i) to[out=   18*\k-18*\jj,in=180-18*\k+18*\jj] (\k\i);
  }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know what the question wants to know, but I know this answer looks awesome!

Comment: @FHZ, thanks!!!